# Why VS Code "Some content has been disabled in this document" in preview and not showing in "live server" while applying CSS external sheet to HTML?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have just started learning HTML and CSS, after linking the CSS external sheet, there is no change in "preview" as well as the "live server". In preview there is a blue text shown as "Some content has been disabled in this document" and there is no sign of the CSS sheet applied to the HTML in the "live server".

I have tried all the solutions on the internet, checked the path as well but none were really useful no change. I need your help; I'm waiting for your responses if anyone have any idea, please help me out.